# android : cannot build project after upgrading Android Studio to 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

So, happily updated my Android Studio from stable version 2.2 to canary channel 2.3.

But, unfortunately, it has serious bug. Project is not able to build.
I tried opening my previous projects and also tried creating new sample application, I got same below error:

```
Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

**build.gradle(project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chint.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Am I the only one with this issue ?

Comment: Down voting with proper reason will always be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, be careful while this dialog appears:

[image]

**Choose** "Remind me later" and **NOT** "Update"

Stay with the build version you already have.

Incase, you pressed Update, so just rollback your Android Gradle Plugin classpath in `build.gradle(project)` to below one:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your Android Studio gradle manually.

**1° Step:**

Follow this path and get your gradle version

```
C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

Here you will get  "gradle-X.X" (X- is version) in my case it was "gradle-3.3-all"

**2° Step:**

Go to the following link :

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Download your respective version zip file and just past it in the last folder with long random name.

`C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-x.x\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc31212` **HERE**

Now open the Android studio, I hope this will work.

Comment: make some formatting so it look like a better readable answer

Comment: Yup Gahan, Thanks Dwhitz

Answer (score 0):

I fought a similar issue and resolved it with the addition of **2 characters**...

And after updating the `gradle-wrapper.properties` to target 3.2.1 everything was great for me

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you import external libraries apply  changes for "allprojects"

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```